# sql query left join on mysql vs ms-access DB

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, ms-access, oledbcommand

this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblContracts 
LEFT JOIN tblPartys ON tblContracts.id = tblPartys.Contract_id 
INNER JOIN tblAdministrators 
        ON tblContracts.AdministratorID = tblAdministrators.ID
```

works on mysql Database but it doesn't work on Access DB !!!

I am getting this error blow:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error (missing operator) in
>   query expression 'tblContracts.id = tblPartys.Contract_id INNER JOIN
>   tblAdministrators ON tblContracts.AdministratorID =
>   tblAdministrators.I'. at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)

Comment: You should also include the code you are executing against the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a couple of parenthesis around the first join

```
SELECT * 
FROM (tblContracts 
LEFT JOIN tblPartys ON tblContracts.id = tblPartys.Contract_id) 
INNER JOIN tblAdministrators 
        ON tblContracts.AdministratorID = tblAdministrators.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error you posted, you miswrite `ON tblContracts.AdministratorID = tblAdministrators.ID` into `ON tblContracts.AdministratorID = tblAdministrators.I` as explained:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'tblContracts.id = tblPartys.Contract_id INNER JOIN tblAdministrators ON tblContracts.AdministratorID = tblAdministrators.I'. at ...

So ensure that it is written like `ON tblContracts.AdministratorID = tblAdministrators.ID`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT *  FROM ((tblContracts 
   LEFT JOIN tblPartys ON tblContracts.id = tblPartys.Contract_id ) 
     INNER JOIN tblAdministrators ON tblContracts.AdministratorID = tblAdministrators.ID )
```

In my experience, Access likes parentheses...a little too much, if you ask me.